# C# BeginInvoke in BackgroundWorker, get object property value

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, backgroundworker, trackbar

I have a `trackbar` on a WinForm. I am performing some operation in `BackgroundWorker`. I am using `BeginInvoke` to access UI elements. Now i can easily set the `trackbar` value using:

`trackbar.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => trackbar.Value = 50))`.

How do i get the trackbar current value using `BeginInvoke` in the `BackgroundWorker`?

`length = trackbar.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => trackbar.Value))` doesn't compile.

`trackbar.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => length = trackbar.Value))` compiles but doesn't work.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you not pass in your trackbar value at the start? With bw.RunWorkerAsync(trackbar.Value); then keep a local copy within the DoWork event? Then each time you need to update the value of the trackbar you update the local copy then continue to use the BeginInvoke to update it.

Comment: No, i have to get the current value of the trackbar which the user has set at runtime.

Comment: Is that because you're starting the background worker at the start and then leaving it running forever? Ideally you'd only have the background worker running while it needs to be running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with `BeginInvoke`, because what it does is it posts a message internally (literally `PostMessage`) and returns without processing it.

You need to use `Invoke` instead, which sends the message, processes it, and only then resumes your function:

```
int length;
trackbar.Invoke((Action)(() => length = trackbar.Value));
```

It goes without saying that this kind of code in a tight loop will kill your performance. Use `Invoke` with care!

Comment: No, because you're using `SendMessage` to read it. TrackBar is a Windows Common Control.

Comment: Thank you so much @Blindy, you saved the day. On your remarks about "Killing Performance", no `Invoke` is not inside loop. But what if i need to update a `progressbar` in each iteration of a loop? What would you suggest i use? `BeginInvoke`?

Comment: Depends, if you flood your message queue with a lot of `BeginInvoke` messages you'll also kill performance. My suggestion is to use `BeginInvoke`, but throttle how many you send out -- ie send one every second or so, and drop any inbetween.

Comment: The general rule of thumb is `Invoke` when you need data *out* of the GUI thread, and `BeginInvoke` otherwise. And as little as possible. And consider if you even need data out, you might get the job done by pushing the logic inside the invoke message, and process it all on the GUI thread -- if you can't avoid invoking, at least don't block your other thread too!

Comment: BackgroundWorker has a built in ReportProgress event for sending progress updates, why would you use Invoke/BeginInvoke!

Comment: So for example, i am renaming one hundred thousand files in a loop, if i add one second delay, it will add up to 27.77 hours at least. How do i handle this???

Comment: Ok forget about progress bar, say i need to update some other GUI control in each iteration, what then?

Comment: You can rename files on a background thread without having to use invoke/begininvoke. It'll cripple your disc IO while it runs but it'll leave your UI nice and responsive.

Comment: ReportProgress takes two params, an int and an object. You can use a custom class to contain whatever state you want then fire ReportProgress and pass in your custom class. You can set the progress param to 0 if you don't care about setting a progress bar. In the progress handler you can update your UI with whatever is in your custom class.

Comment: Two things are my primary concern, responsive UI and performance. Now i need to get value from the trackbar, start a loop, and update UI upon each iteration. So i have to use Invoke/BeginInvoke.

Comment: Which as Blindy stated will kill your performance. You can chain DoWorks by kicking off RunWorkerAsync again when RunWorkerCompleted fires - you can check whether you need to restart then if you do get the trackbar value and pass it into the next run of RunWorkerAsync.

Comment: If you are processing 100,000 things, don't update the UI once per thing, update it once per 1000 things (i.e. about 100 times).  You could even update it once every 2000 things (50-ish times)